# Meteor: Subscribe for getting more datas doesn't work

Tags: javascript, meteor, publish-subscribe

I'm having a problem with Meteor, I have two subscribes : one is used in the main page, while the second one is called on a specific page. The 1st returns some datas about all the users, and the second returns all the datas from one specific user, but my problem is that this subscribe doesn't work on the first loading of the page.
I think that, to the extent that I already have datas from that particular user, the subscribe is not used; if I refresh the page, I have all the correct datas...

I really don't know what to do, thanks for your attention!

Comment: Do you use iron router ?

Comment: No, but since Publish / Subscribe works perfectly, the error is somewhere else. Can you edit your route and add the waitOn parameter ? An exemple from one of my project : this.route('viewer', {
    path: 'viewer/:_id',
    data: function () {
      return {
        img: Images.findOne({_id: this.params._id})
      }
    },
    waitOn: function() {
      return Meteor.subscribe('imgInfo', this.params._id);
    },
  });

Comment: I subscribe with waitOn, it does what it has to do, it is executed before creating the template, the code uses the correct publish, but nothing is returned... I think that it's because I already have datas about users and when I want more datas from a particular user the publish function maybe thinks I already have enough datas

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to figure out where the problem is without any code. Make sure your subscriptions are being run whenever that page is visited or that template is created. This means putting the sub either at the router level in the `waitOn` or `subscriptions` functions, or putting the sub at the template level within its onCreated callback: `Template.myTemp.onCreated = function() { this.subscribe('myPub'); }`